# Rename [sql-server] tag to [ms-sql-server]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

Every day I can see [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624832/sql-database-memory-and-performance) about MySQL tagged [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). I fix it several times per day, but we can not explain to all users the difference between SQL Server and MySQL.

Maybe we should rename [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) to something more obvious, [ms-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) or [microsoft-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-sql-server)?

Comment: How about renaming [tag:mysql] to [tag:oracle-mysql] then, too? =)

Comment: [tag:mysql] is a clearly defined database server. SQL Server is a general term (like Database) and I think it is incorrect that we use this tag for SQL Server of MS.  Anyway I have not seen people who asked about MS SQL and use [tag:mysql], bu every day I see many questions about MySQl with [tag:sql-server]

Comment: @demas Consistency. Otherwise it's hard to know on what tag, where, and how, to disambiguate.

Comment: And even http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system

Comment: Every day I see many questions about Oracle with MySQL or SQL without mentioning what RDBMS they're using at all... I don't see how this is any different?

Comment: @Ben, you are talking about the problem, but you don't offer any solution of this promlem.  Do you ?

Comment: Read the first comment on the MSE question you linked; there is no easy solution (also read Aaron's answer). The problem is often the OP not knowing what they're using/doing, for which there is no technical solution.

Comment: This proposal seems an _easy_, _simple_ way of discouraging users from misapplying the sql-server tag. +1

Comment: +1. Since I seldom touch MS SQL server, whenever I encounter "SQL server", it always makes me think *which SQL server?*

Comment: @Ben, this is different because of the way the expression "SQL server" is used. When people say, "*we'll store that in the/our SQL server*", it's generally not product specific. In contrast, when they say "*we'll store that in SQL Server*", they refer to MS SQL Server 99% of the time (often without even thinking that this can be ambiguous).

Comment: This is different to what @Bruno? It's identical to the duplicate (which has now been deleted). I don't really see how it's ambiguous either - it's a product name. To re-post my comment from the dupe _"a SQL Server doesn't really exist... you mean a database server, i.e. a server specifically configured to run databases. SQL is just a language and doesn't have to run on a database server (though it must run against a database)."_

Comment: @Bruno that's not really something people say (hopefully) who know anything about databases. Just because it's common, if ignorant, usage doesn't mean we should design our tags around it.

Comment: @Ben you are 100% correct. You store the data in a database on a database server. Nobody talks about "connecting to the .NET server", it's a web server running MVC or whatever.

Comment: @JNK, I'm afraid I've heard that sort of phrasing many times, maybe not those exact words, but even coming from people who know reasonably well what they're doing. It's just that they're so used to an MS-only environment that the notion you may be talking of other types of SQL servers doesn't necessarily occur to them at first. "Oracle" is somewhat less ambiguous. People often talk about "Oracle" when referring to their SQL server, but at least it's clear it's a brand name (and generally from the context, they're not referring to other Oracle products).

Comment: @Bruno it's not common phrasing with database professionals, I can tell you that.

Comment: @JNK, do you mean talking of a "SQL server" (not "SQL Server") isn't common phrasing amongst database professionals? (We see to agree on that fact MS SQL Server professionals refer to it simply as "SQL Server".) That may be true, but remember the users on SO might be developers without being DBAs. To them, a "SQL server" may just be whatever server they can query with SQL.

Comment: @Bruno Should we retag all web development questions with "Chrome" then since I get to my web pages that way? We're arguing about semantics here when in fact this proposal will not address the actual root cause of the issue.

Comment: [This improvement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) I suggested would fix this.

Comment: @JNK you mean [tag:Google-Chrome] off course ;)

Comment: So, I guess the solution would be to rename Microsoft SQL Server to something. Not the tag but the product.

Comment: @GolezTrol I fail to see how that "solution" would address anything (never mind how you could convince Microsoft that this is their problem).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Do you actually fail to see how confusion about an ambiguous name can be solved by renaming the product that carries that name? I wasn't completely serious, since Microsoft probably won't be convinced to rename their product because of some tag-ambiguity on SO, but if they would, I don't see how that would *not* solve this issue (in the long run, when people start forgetting the old name).

Comment: @GolezTrol First of all, it's not going to happen. Second, the name has become ambiguous long after "SQL Server" was a product, and in fact I suspect that was mostly influenced by the presence of said product. Again, I feel to see how changing the specific product name will erase all of this history or make people who don't know the difference between `mysql` and `sql-server` smarter.

Comment: On the flip side, there's probably just as many people who are using `MS SQL Server`, but they still also tag their question with `MySQL` because, well, it is THEIR SQL...

Comment: I suggest it rename to mssql, mssq-2008, mssql-2012 and so on...

Answer (score 16):

As a mod on the [Database site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) I have some familiarity with this kind of issue, and the kind of askers who will make the mistake.

**I do not think this will have any impact whatsoever.**

The people who misapply the `sql-server` tag are not paying any attention to what they are doing when they tag the question, period.

Lest we forget, all the tags have nice helpful messages when you type into the tag dialog at the bottom of the question. As of about 30 seconds ago, this is a screenshot of the first 3 entries when you type `sql`:

[image]

The very first word under `sql-server` is **Microsoft**.  *The first word.*

This is not a tag clarity issue, it's a user issue that won't be solved by renaming a tag.

Comment: I actually doubt that the people making those mistakes necessarily pay attention to the small prints under the tag, unfortunately. Making the tag name more explicit would probably help.

Comment: @Bruno What makes you think they will pay more attention to `ms-` than they would to the word `Microsoft` directly below the tag? The point is, they aren't paying attention **at all**.

Comment: It's in the name, you have to type it... Especially is `sql-server` is blacklisted, they'll *have* to think about what they mean by "SQL [sS]server".

Comment: @Bruno they won't, that's the problem. Believe me I deal with this a lot and have had to think about it a great deal. Additionally, very few people who deal with SQL Server professionally ever call it "MS SQL Server", it's just "SQL Server" so you are essentially advocating irritating/frustrating/confusing domain experts in favor of catering to a class of askers who **by definition** are extremely careless and pay little attention to what they are doing.

Comment: Ah, yes, so we agree, people who deal with "MS SQL Server" only very rarely call it anything else than "SQL Server". The problem is that people who use other types of SQL servers (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...) refer to them as their "SQL servers", since it's a more generic term. If when you start typing the tag "sql-server" it autosuggests "ms-sql-server" or "microsoft-sql-server", those who really mean "MS SQL Server" would obviously find what they know and need, those who meant it in a non-specific way would have to re-think. Better clarify for both parties.

Comment: @Bruno Why do you keep saying that MySQL or Postgresql are "SQL Servers"?, they are not, they are "relational database management systems". And one of them is SQL Server (which is from Microsoft)

Comment: MySQL and Postgres are RDBMS, not servers. The server is the box or VM that the database instance lives on. The product is called "SQL Server". Do we have "MS-CSharp" or "MS-ASP.NET" tags or is the company inferred from the product name? You're advocating solving the wrong problem here, which is that the people who ask these questions and incorrectly tag them do not pay attention to what they are doing.

Comment: @Bruno I don't think so that people who use Postgres or MySQL or Oracle refer to their server as "SQL Server". Sometimes they may refer to them as "sql server" but when writing to a SO site, the serious users or database professionals know better that "SQL-Server" means the "Microsoft SQL-Server" product.

Comment: The term "SQL Server" is coined and trademarked by Microsoft. I have never spoken with or chatted with anyone that while talking about other DBMS referenced them as "SQL server".

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you when you talk about people who know what they're talking about. I'm saying some developers who are not necessarily idiots, but who are not in the field and trying to learn by asking questions, *would* make this sort of mistake when tagging their questions on SO, even if it's otherwise a good question.

Comment: @Bruno I doubt it. A good question by a user that made the slightest effort or research will know the relevant technology involved

Comment: "*MySQL and Postgres are RDBMS, not servers. The server is the box or VM that the database instance lives on.*" Hum... not really, "server" can either mean the box or the software that's listening to client connections. Package names and descriptions (e.g. [`mysql-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/mysql-server): "*MySQL is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server.*") can lead to confusion.

Comment: @Lamak, as I was saying earlier, all the people I know who use "MS SQL Server" refer to it as "SQL Server" (I think we'd agree on that), the problem is that there's also a completely different group of people who've only ever used MySQL for example, and who've never had much exposure to "SQL Server" who use "SQL server" more loosely. They're not necessarily idiots who haven't research enough, they've just stayed in their MySQL environment without realising this terminology issue at all. This is what a tag rename would help with.

Comment: a tooth is much more prized than a diamond

Comment: @Bruno Well, then we also need to think on the guys that will see the microsoft-sql-server tag and think "well, I'm using MySQL in windows, so it's a sql server from microsoft". I think that the tag rename will be useless in almost every way

Comment: @Lamak, there's surely fewer people who'd make that confusion. All I'm saying is that people who know what they're talking about will only use `sql-server` for the MS product. However, for people who don't quite know the database world (and many askers will be in that category, without being stupid), it's quite easy to get confused (as I said above "*MySQL is a [...] SQL database server*" is a package description). It's quite easy to drop the "database" word from there, especially when you're not aware of "MS" SQL Server. (...)

Comment: (...cont'd...) The only purpose of that tag-rename is to have fewer questions on the `sql-server` tag that are in fact related to other RDBMS. Remember that those who initially tag are the askers, who don't necessarily have a complete picture of the field (and it's not like terminology is always clear and consistent, I mean "schema", "instance", "database", "cluster", can mean different things with different RDBMS).

Comment: Even [Wikipedia doesn't help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server): "*SQL Server may refer to: - Any database server that implements the Structured Query Language, - Microsoft SQL Server, a relational database server from Microsoft, [...]*". I'm certainly not saying Wikipedia or other sources are *right*, I'm just saying that it's legitimate to expect some askers to be confused.

Comment: Renaming the tag for the sake of people who have no idea what they are talking about is neither necessary, expedient, nor helpful for anyone who actually does know.  Whenever I see a MySQL question tagged with SQL Server I immediately downgrade my expectation of the OP, ask for clarification (educate the OP), and remove the errant tag.  As for Wikipedia; really?

Comment: So, summing up this post: The domain expert / pure microsoft guy has no trouble with his terminology, and if anyone else has; tough luck, somebody elses problem, I am right(tm).

Comment: @Deduplicator *sigh*, you should read the post again if that's the summary you are getting

Comment: @Deduplicator More like: Anyone who pays any attention to what they are doing when they apply tags has no issue with the current terminology. Anyone who DOES won't be helped by this change since they are already not paying attention.

Comment: To sum up; 4 people with 12k total upvotes in the SQL tag are against this request. Everyone else who's against has less than 1k total. If you exclude GolzeTrol it's more like 300. The people who actually interact with the tag are against the change the people who don't are in favour...

Comment: I disagree. I see many of these mix-up every day. why renaming the sql-server if so hard that you are resisting it?

Answer (score 0):

Disagree.

SQL Server is the name of a product, like OSX, or Excel. No one says Google Android, it's just Android.

The term *SQL Server* has no technical meaning anyway. I could understand your point if Microsoft had called the product "Database Server" or "RDBMS Server".

Comment: A SQL server is any database server that uses SQL, not just the MS one. That MS can't name things is nothing new.

Answer (score -2):

I'm in favor of renaming the tag to `ms-sql-server`. The other tags should not necessarily be renamed to, but `sql server` sounds so generic that it confused users.

I don't worry about the tag being unfindable, because when you start typing anything in the tag box, it suggests all tags that *contain* the typed text. So people who type `sql-server` will automatically find ms-sql-server.

Of course people will make mistakes mizing up other RDBMSses as well, but my feeling is that those errors are significantly less frequent.

Answer (score -2):

I support the renaming to [microsoft-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-sql-server) but we should make sure that [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) is NOT a synonym of it (I'd recommend blacklisting it because of its ambiguity) or it won't help a lot.

Comment: I'd say blacklisting `sql-server` would be a requirement for this to work. This would also have the positive effect of encouraging askers to specify which RDBMS they're using.

Answer (score -2):

I really want someone pay attention to this question. I'm tired of asking OPs: "Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?" I request moderators to change all `sql-server-????` to `mssql-????`. I have thousands of examples which OPs tag sql-server while their question is about other RDBMS.

Comment: The [[tag:sql-server]] tag never means MySQL. It is not necessary to ever ask when you see this tag used. It means Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I'm REALLY wondering how a pro member says this. When someone ask question and uses both MySQL and sql-server tag, it is necessary to ask if which one did he meant, otherwise how we provide the proper answer???

Comment: The problem there is not the [sql-server] tag. It's that someone used two contradictory tags. That problem cannot be fixed through the tag system.

Comment: I think the tag system tends to suggest the contradictory tags for sql questions and people just accept the suggestions - that used to be the case last time I tested this anyway

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike But the tag name alone `[sql-server]` and `[mysql]` aren't contractionary. MySQL is a SQL server, just like any database server that uses SQL. Using the name SQL server to refer to only a single product or only a part of SQL products and not all of them is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

I would like to mention another reason for why it would be a very good idea to drop the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag.

Microsoft SQL Server may be one of the best SQL server products in existence, perhaps even currently the best; however, this does not give Microsoft the right to usurp the term "SQL Server" for their product only.  There are many SQL Server products out there, Microsoft's is just one of them. Since about 2001 I have been cringing whenever I hear it being referred to as "SQL Server" as if it was the one and only SQL server, the only true SQL server, the SQL server to rule them all.

The official name of the product is "Microsoft SQL Server", Microsoft made the conscious choice to call it like that, it should be called like that. I guess it is inevitable that it will be abbreviated to just "SQL Server" in casual conversations, (since the official name is a bit of a tongue twister,) but any non-casual mention of the name of the product (such as in a stackexchange tag) should not be adding legitimacy to the usurpation of the term by Microsoft.

Therefore, I propose that the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag be dropped, and replaced with the existing [ms-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) tag, or perhaps even a [microsoft-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-sql-server) tag.

<sup>(While at it, let us also remove the [sql-srever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-srever) tag.)</sup>

Comment: Disagree. SQL Server is the name of a product, like OSX, or Excel. No one says Google Android, it's just Android. The term SQL Server has no technical meaning, and is in no way synonymous with Database Server.

Comment: @tomredfern no, SQL Server has plenty of technical meaning; all server RDBMSes are SQL Servers. Microsoft SQL Server is not more SQLey than MySQL or Postgress or Oracle are SQLey.  They are all things that you send SQL to and receive result sets from.  When writing code, the only reason why you are think of yourself as sending your query to your database server, instead of your SQL server, is because the latter term has been appropriated by Microsoft.

Comment: @tomredfern: "SQL server" is definitely not synonymous with "database server".  The latter term includes relational database servers defined and queried with SQL, relational database servers queried with other syntax, and non-relational database servers.  It is a superset of "SQL server".

Comment: @BenVoigt - as I said, the terms are not synonymous.

Comment: @tomredfern: Yet it does have a meaning as a generic term, despite your comment claiming it does not.  "SQL server" is a smaller category than "database server" but a larger category than "Microsoft SQL Server" (and strictly speaking, "Microsoft SQL Server" is not even an SQL server because its query language is T-SQL which does not support the entire SQL international standard).