# Can we get a warning when a user tags multiple DBMSs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I know that when a user tags a database question with SQL, we see the following message:

[image]

It does mention that it gets better answers if they include "**one** specific database engine". However, if I don't use this tag but were to simply tag my question as [MySQL] and [SQL-Server] no message would appear. This of course leads to the constantly repeated (though necessary) comment of:

> Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are totally different products.

I think it would be a great benefit to have a similar message appear anytime a user tags multiple database engines, whether it's MySQL/SQLite or SQLite/SQL-Server or whatever. This will prompt the user to (hopefully) stop and select only the proper database engine, or at the very least include their reasoning for tagging both.

To elaborate on that last statement, there are cases where a user may be interested in a universal solution, or their question is in regards to a difference between the two DBMS, so certainly it isn't an action that should be outlawed. However, a question like that would be much improved upon if it had some clarification by the user for why both tags are relevant.

Another option (as opposed to creating a separate warning about multiple DBMS) could include making this same message appear for all database engine tags, not just the SQL tag.

Does anyone else think this feature would be beneficial? Is there a downside (other than developer time required)? Would a feature like that be too difficult or time consuming to implement?

Comment: I'm concerned with what is considered a DBMS? And then who is making that decision (community as a whole, 10k+ users, tag wiki edits privilege, etc)? Personally, I think it's a problem that can be easily resolved in the comments if it needs to be. If OP doesn't reply to the comments and/or edit the question to clarify why it has multiple DBMS tags, I think the question could be put on hold being too broad.

Comment: Sure, it can be resolved in comments, but I can't count the number of times I've had to see it happen. Certainly we can eliminate some of the unnecessary repetitive conversations by extending this warning to another similar circumstance?

Comment: The problem with little warnings over everything is that you end up with little warnings _everywhere_.  Though this can be an issue it normally gets sorted quickly if there's a genuine issue (it is sometimes intentional after all).

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find the meta post, but someone must have made the decision that the [sql] tag deserved that warning? Why is *that* warning important enough, but this scenario which causes the same bits of confusion doesn't?

Comment: [The feature request of the warning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632)

Comment: @StevenV thanks for sharing. There are even some comments on that thread that go over this idea.

Comment: I wonder if half of the problem won't be solved by renaming the sql-server tag to "microsoft-sql-server". I think newbies tend to use it because they figure their question is about SQL running on a server.

Comment: @RealSkeptic that's not a bad idea. It may clear up some confusion, but doesn't make it any better when a user tags mysql and microsoft-sql-server.

Comment: @RealSkeptic [Asked before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262934/792066), don't know why that one was so unpopular but this one is...

Comment: Keep in mind also that this likely opens Pandora's box for other similar situations, such as questions tagged both C and C++, which I see a fair number of. While the languages have similar roots, idiomatic solutions vary greatly between the languages and I have no problem asking in the comments to clarify which they need.