# Tags that could conflict with each other warning

Tags: feature-request, tags

I looks like this was previously discussed here, [Can we get a warning when a user tags multiple DBMSs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286965/can-we-get-a-warning-when-a-user-tags-multiple-dbmss), however, I do wonder if this can be expanded on. This is something I see very commonly when viewing questions about how to do something on an RDBMS, however, I very much doubt it is limited specifically to RDBMS's.

One thing I see a lot is that users will tag multiple RDBMS when asking a question, however, the syntax between say [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) is very different. There might not be anything with the question the user has made, however, it is impossible to provide an answer as you don't know what RDBMS they are using. This means that the first few comments are all asking for clarity on what RDBMS the OP is using.

Sometimes the RDBMS can easily be determined, due to the SQL that the user has provided (if you see a query referring to an object called something like `dbo.MyTable` you know it's SQL Server).

It's not, however, just limited to RDBMS tags though. I've seen, for example, several occasions where a questions tags have [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin). PHP MyAdmin is a web interface for interacting with MySQL; it has nothing to do with SQL Server; so the tags also conflict (and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) isn't even tagged).

I think it would be useful for the user to just be notified that they have tags that conflict and to confirm that they are correct; a simple warning letting them know which ones conflict.  As I said before, I doubt this is unique to RDBMS, but it is very prevalent there. This would make people asking questions experience a little better (they aren't asked several times for details on what RDBMS they are using), and makes it easier for those trying to answer, as they don't have to query it or second guess.

Comment: it would be useful. having saved about 5 seconds on editing the tags that could have been used to take a bite out this cookie **edit** the cookie has been eaten this was good time