# Incorrect tag suggestions when posting a C or C++ question

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, suggested-tags

Incorrect use of [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in the same question has been a long source of unclear posts and conflicts. To deal with that problem, the community established rules for cross-tagging in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis) meta discussion which then lead to the current [C tag usage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) and [C++ tag usage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) rules. From that we learn that the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags should *not* be used together unless the question is explicitly about differences between the two languages, such as questions regarding compatibility and porting.

Now I just posted a C question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252570/why-are-const-qualified-variables-accepted-as-initializers-on-gcc) and when I did so, the site incorrectly suggests that I should add the C++ tag, even though my question has absolutely nothing to do with C++. As it happens, the question is even about a language feature which is completely different in C and C++. Had I added the C++ tag like the site suggests, my question would have become too broad and unclear.

I realized that this suggested tags feature is very likely a source of needless mistagging. It is clearly too blunt and probably just looks at tags that are usually used together. (C and C++ both are often used with the gcc tag, probably why.)

Ideally it should be possible to configure the suggested tags feature with specific rules to avoid incorrect tagging. Or alternatively disable it for tags where it causes harm.

Comment: Maybe someone could even conjure statistics regarding incorrect tagging from the point where the suggested tags feature was introduced, whenever that was. It would be interested to see if this feature has indeed statistically lead to an increased cross tagging of C and C++.

Comment: It probably suggested that because, funny enough, `c++` is the most used tag in conjuncture with `c` - with more than 38k questions. The next in line is just with 27k questions. It is not true the other way around. `c` is *"only"* the third-most used tag with `c++`

Comment: I doubt fiddling with the suggestions for additional tags will do much. I would have thought that the primary culprit is the fact that typing `c` into the tag bar (before even adding any tags), immediately gives `c` and `c++` as suggestions. And... well... that's valid as suggestion, and unfortunately may be just as likely to make the "C/C++" people tags  with both. Although.... now that I tried it again, it doesn't... That's good.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. If you want the system to stop suggesting both tags, you need to address @Tomerikoo fact.

Comment: @Lundin this doesn't look like a [bug] but rather a [feature-request]?

Comment: @Lino A feature that doesn't work as intended is a bug. It suggests tags that it shouldn't be suggesting. The problem is with the implementation of the suggested tag feature, so it is a bug.

Comment: It's a stretch calling it a bug or a feature request. The tag suggestion is supposed to evaluate the content of previous posts and recognize these patterns and suggest the tags these posts have. The system is behaving as intended. The data it's fed of is the problem here.

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, the recommended tags are based on tags that are frequently used with said tag. According tp a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1431666) there are almost 40,000 questions where both [[tag:c]] and [[tag:c++]] are tagged. The feature is working as expected, the problem is the misuse of the tags (and really the wrong tag needs to be removed from questions where it's wrong).

Comment: I don't know if I should laugh and cry when programmers think that upon implementing a feature, it isn't a bug if you read the requirements wrong, state the wrong requirements or have no requirements at all ("aimlessly hack away"). Either of those three scenarios is a common example of the most severe kind of bugs there are.

Comment: In fact after [[tag:c++11]] and [[tag:qt]] the most common tag to be used with [[tag:c++]] *is* [[tag:c]], and the most common tag used with [[tag:c]] is [[tag:c++]]: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1431668). It's not a "bug" that the recommendation system is working exactly as intended when the tags are ***very*** often used in common with the other. The problem, again, is that users are incorrectly tagging; fix the tagging, fix the problem. Of course, that's hard now, but *good* curation is key here.

Comment: @Larnu Although, why would I use a tag just because it is commonly used? That actually doesn't make any sense. The _content_ of my question is what should determine which tags to use. For example, if the _body_ of my question contains "C++" in several places. Not because of some "other users who bought this product also like..." algorithm.

Comment: Just because *you* aren't doesn't mean others aren't, @Lundin . Clearly people commonly use [[tag:c++]] and [[tag:c]] together often (or people haven't been curating the questions well), and thus the system is suggesting the tag as it's a likely candidate that will want to be tagged too. That doesn't, however, mean should tag it because it's suggestion, which is again why curation (and education) is important.

Comment: Similar features, such as defining "conflicting tags" have been suggested in the past and got no traction. [Can we get a warning when a user tags multiple DBMSs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286965/2029983), or an extension on the I asked, [Tags that could conflict with each other warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368090/2029983).

Comment: We used to have a line in the C++ tag wiki about not asking about the likes of `++i++`, complete with links Q&A pages that explained what was going on, and still saw the question or derivatives at least once a day. No one reads the tag wikis until it's too late. But that's another "solve the human problem" problem.

Comment: @user4581301 The tag wiki isn't some place new users goes for help & to read up about the tag. Nobody does that indeed. It's a place where you collect rules and information, so that you know where to find it if you need it.

Comment: Also, "fix humans" is the lamest kind of argument. They've been pretty much the same for thousands of years. Design a UI suitable for human users is on the other hand a valid argument.

Comment: @Braiam You make it sound like runaway feedback, which would be a bug in the design.

Comment: @AndrewMorton not if the feedback is sustained for [long periods of time and never corrected.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1432374/how-many-questions-had-a-specific-tag-added)

Comment: Relevant: [How are “Suggested Tags” chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907/213575)

Answer (score 46):

Having an automatic tool suggesting to put both a C tag and a C++ tag on a question **is simply a bug**. There is really not more to discuss. **It's a bug and it must be fixed.**

C and C++ are different. While C++ covers most of C (but not fully), C is far from covering most of C++. Further - perhaps even worse - a good solution in C is in many cases the wrong solution in C++. And a good C++ solution is in many cases something that you can't even do in C.

In some cases a question can be answered with a solution that is fine for both C and C++. But such questions may also be answered by solutions that are pure C or pure C++. So a SO visitor looking for a C solution may find a question tagged with C and an answer which is for C++ only. That's bad. We don't want visitors to have to figure out by themself which language an answer applies to.

So C and C++ should be kept apart (with exceptions as already mentioned in the question). So obviously we can't have a tool misguiding users to put both tags on their question.

The "tag-suggestion-tool" must be fixed like:

```
if (C in tag-list AND C++ in tag-list)
   display-big-sign("Are you really sure that this question is to be
                     tagged with both C and C++")
   answer = get_answer_from_user()
   if (answer == YES)
       display-even-bigger-sign("Are you really, really, really sure
                                 that this question is to be tagged
                                 with both C and C++")
```

And while the bug is being fixed, please consider including other languages as well. We get way too many questions tagged with various combination of C, C++, C#, and Python for no reason.

Comment: I think _must_ be fixed is overstating things.  _Should_ be fixed? Maybe.  But it's something that should be considered alongside other things such as availability of development resources, feature priority, difficulty of fix, addition of complexity (e.g. one-off custom code), etc.  Sure, it leads to incorrect human behavior resulting in an incorrect system state, but on the other hand, it doesn't lead to anything irreversible (e.g. data loss) and can be fixed even by users with almost no reputation.

Comment: See also this feature-request to have the system discourage unlikely tag-combos that often result from people not reading tag popups, just the names, for abbreviations: [Stop users from tagging SSE and Sever-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150)

Comment: @M.Justin I disagree, having C question will often return results in C++ which is clearly wrong, but question was tagged with both languages. Should you downvote such answer because someone used wrong tag? As said in answer: "good solution in C is wrong for C++" and vice versa.

Comment: At least the source of the C++/Python confusion is obvious. They share a lot of the same letters.

Comment: To augment your logic: once the user selects the C or C++ tags for their question, the UI should stop suggesting the other one.  The confirmation dialog should only be necessary when the user goes out of their way to manually add the second tag.  Even better would be if the language was selected by a different mechanism entirely and the tag suggestor only suggested non-language tags.

Comment: @M.Justin "must be fixed" vs. "should be fixed" is a bit of a nitpick to mee. Anyway, it's obvious that even "must be fixed" issues have severity levels that are part of prioritizing which issues to solve first, I don't disagree about that. But when you write " it doesn't lead to anything irreversible ... and can be fixed even by users with almost no reputation" I disagree. Example: A question ....

Comment: (cont.) ..... with both tags gets two answers before the wrong tagging is addressed. Answer A is a C++ only solution and answer B is a C only solution. How can that be solved? And in case OP never tells whether it's for C or C++, how can it be solved? Shall we torse a coin to decide which tag to delete? And then hope for the answer for the deleted tag gets downvoted.

Comment: This implementation ignores an important reality: anyone can create any tags and the system should be able to suggest newly created tags without developer intervention. The current tag suggestion system deals with this.

Comment: @Braiam Apperently the current tag suggestion system doesn't even deal with long existing tags

Comment: It does. It suggest tags based on the text content of the previous questions and how similar is to the one you are asking.

Answer (score -8):

It is? Really? I mean, you guys [literally hijack C questions to make them about C++ too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb3U3.png), instead of just having your own version of it. Obviously the system would see this, act rationally and presume that all questions that have text related to C or C++ should have both tags.

The system is working as intended taking the signals that the users give them to suggest tags. If you are seeing a problem with the suggestion system, there are ways to manipulate it without having to spend developers time, namely feeding the system with good data, [go through this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20%5Bc%5D%20%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) and remove the irrelevant tags. The system after all is [very likely machine learning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238638/213575), which means that the model presumes that the information they are fed is correct (asking SO to make a better ML model is obviously unrealistic, since which what data would the feed it?).

Comment: Which of the C and C++ tags are you suggesting is irrelevant?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler whichever isn't relevant to the question asked. If people ask a C/C++ question, just close it as unclear.

Comment: "You guys" is one single confused user who made an edit in 2010. And since you don't participate in either tag, if you are at all participating on the main site and not just meta, nobody cares about your subjective opinions. How can you know anything about how the site or specific tags works if you don't use them?

Comment: I spend a lot of time in the C-tag and in my experience it's very rare that someone adds e.g. a C++ tag to a question which initially only has a C tag. And your example seems to from 2010. Seriously, are you suggesting that this 10 years old example is causing a tool to give bad tag suggestions today? Really?

Comment: "The system is working as intended ...." Well, in principal the system may work in accordance with a given requirement specification - true. But if so it's the requirement specification which is wrong. No matter where you place the responsebility, the fact is that the final outcome is a system that doesn't work.

Comment: @4386427 "it's very rare that someone adds e.g. a C++ tag to a question which initially only has a C tag" Your experience is n=1. [It happened about ~1.3k times.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1432374/how-many-questions-had-a-specific-tag-added), most of  them 2010 to 2015. There are enough of them to have swayed the tag engine into thinking that they are sufficiently related. See later years how the numbers fall, because the system starts suggesting both tags so they are added less via edits

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for proving that it happens rarely. E.g. 75 times in all 2020 that's rare compared to the number of C questions posted.

Comment: @Lundin Calling sbi “confused” is a bit weird. Before quitting Stack Overflow he was one of the most senior, prolific and knowledgeable C++ answerers (just look at the score and the number of gold badges), and that particular retagging is completely appropriate, and was probably preceded by a consensus-reaching discussion in the C++ chat (so it wasn’t “one single … user” either).

Comment: @KonradRudolph No that retagging is not appropriate. Unspecified behavior, undefined behavior and implementation defined behavior are **not** the same in C and C++. So the retagging is completely **in**appropriate.

Comment: @4386427 They’re not identical, but the concepts are (intentionally and consciously) closely related in both languages, and the answers in this FAQ question address both. Treating and contrasting them in the same answer is entirely appropriate. It’s however a shame that none of the existing answers properly contrasts them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I respectfully disagree

Comment: @Lundin is not a single user. It's a systemic behavior of the edits. Out of the 3k questions in existence with both tags in 2015, at least 1/4 of them was because edits that added the other tag in later date. If that's not a consistent deliberate behavior, I don't know what is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think we even had a chat in 2010. The site was kind of "all over the place" back then. _Everyone_ was confused and there wasn't much in the way of consensus about anything. And that C++ would be allowed to keep a "meta tag" C++-faq was established far later, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Lundin [Chat existed by the time of that retagging](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/05/chat-now-in-public-beta/).

Comment: @Braiam Those numbers don’t show anything about whether the tags are appropriate. And respectfully, you simply don’t have the necessary expertise to judge whether the tag edits are appropriate or not. The fact remains that both tags are appropriate only for a *tiny minority* of all C and C++ questions, and that suggesting them for new questions is unarguably inappropriate. Only somebody not active in both tags (= you) would claim that there’s even an argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph of course, but perfectly explain the behavior of the system and the cause of it: humans add the tag and the system trust that users adding the tag know what they are doing. People arguing with me say that the system is wrong, I'm telling them they are full of it and caused the problem themselves.

Comment: @Braiam Nobody here is wondering *why* the system is making this mistake. I think all involved understand this. It’s just completely irrelevant, since the resulting behaviour is unambiguously undesirable and must be classified as a bug. Your answer and comments imply that you believe that the software system is behaving correctly, and that this bug needs to be “fixed” by changing user behaviour. We’re telling you that you’re wrong. Utterly wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph oh boy, you are a programmer through and trough? No system would be able to avoid this problem without manual user intervention. Yes, it's understandable, but it's a self inflicted wound. User even argue that on some cases both tags should be used. So, how the system should behave on those situations?

Comment: @Braiam It's simply incredible that you keep on defending a system that obviously fails. I'm beginning to think this is personal. Did you implement it?

Comment: @Braiam What are you talking about?! This problem is trivial to avoid. Maybe take it easy on the machine learning Kool-Aid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph then design you a system that is capable of doing what the current one does and avoids the "problems" you harp so much about?

Comment: @4386427 no, I didn't implement it. But this thing is a waste of our collective times instead of doing what we should be doing: making sure questions have the correct tags.