# How do we clean up inconsistent tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, clean-up

I have noticed many users tag DB related questions with both [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).  Today, I have thought of checking existing question with both tags and could see that there are [4859 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+mysql) tagged with both sql-server and mysql.

I believe unless and otherwise you have some questions with migrating from one another, there is no reason tagging both databases.

Do we have any plan or already in-process cleaning?  If not, I know it is a tedious task but we may need to start at some point.

> Note: Though my question is only pointing out these two databases, but
>   in reality, there could be a number possible overlaps with other
>   databases viz. [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle), [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)

This is astonishing to see *four databases* tagged in [35 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+sql-server+postgresql+oracle).  I know some of them may be valid but could guess most of them might need re-tagging.

Comment: There's no automated process for this. Typically if you find a question that's mistagged, you fix it. In the case of large batches of question like this, you can often enlist the help of Meta here with a retag-request or the SOCVR, but the latter typically focuses more on tag burninations rather than mass-retagging.

Comment: @TylerH - Yes, I have been actively asking OPs for the right tags and re-tagging for all the new posts whenever I see it.  I have posted this to bring attention from community that there is something else to clean up too :)

Comment: Can we have a single tag for databases?

Comment: Lots of people are writing software that has to work on both SqlServer and MySQL

Comment: Would renaming sql-server to Microsoft-Sql-Server help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we stop suggesting both Sql-Server and MySql in the suggested tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags) or also [Can we get a warning when a user tags multiple DBMSs?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286965/can-we-get-a-warning-when-a-user-tags-multiple-dbmss)

Comment: @IanRingrose [Probably not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/rename-sql-server-tag-to-ms-sql-server)

Comment: @DavidG - why was my question marked as duplicate? I was not requesting any feature implementation as shown in the duplicate question links.  I'm trying to know what community is expected to do!! Do we keep track of old and modify now and then or do we concern about only new ones?